# How to retrieve all jQuery multi-select values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access a jQuery multi-select thing from my JavaScript code and am getting myself terribly confused. This simple example works fine, alerting with a comma-separated list of the checked items:

http://jsfiddle.net/smontanaro/d0Laxh6j/

Those values are produced with this bit:

```
$('[name=offset]').val()
```

but I don't understand the magic it invokes under the covers. Consequently, I'm having trouble generalizing that to a more useful example.

Consider a slightly different environment. I have a callback function with this structure:

```
function respond(button) {
    var form = button.form;
    ...
}
```

which is called from HTML like so:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="respond(this); return false;">
```

If I use something like this:

```
var group = form.elements["offset"].value;
```

all I get is the first checked value. So, I've got my button and its form. As I understand it, neither are jQuery-specific objects, just plain old JavaScript objects. How do I get from them to a comma-separated string (or better yet, a list of strings) of checkbox values like the simple jsfiddle example yields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably intended to write: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d0Laxh6j/10/)

```
 <input type="button" value="Check Selections"
       onclick="alert($(':input[name=offset] :selected').map(function() { return this.value; }).get() ); return false;">
```

But I would advise strongly against inline JS. Therefore you would want to use:

```
<input type="submit" value="Check Selections">
```

and:

```
var values = $('select[name=offset] :selected').map(function() { 
    return this.value; 
}).get(); //array --> add .join(',') to get list
alert( values );
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d0Laxh6j/11/)

Reference:

-- [**.map() | jQuery API Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**html**

```
<select name="offset" class="multi" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option class="all" value="all">All</option>
    <option class="all" value="actual">Actual</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Check Selections" onclick="alert($('input[name=offset]:checked').val()); return false;">
```

**js**

```
$('.multi').multiselect();
$(".multi").on("change", function () {
    var val = $(this).map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    console.log(val);
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/d0Laxh6j/2/)

Above example will work on change. For your case to get select values on button click you can try this:

```
$('.multi').multiselect();
window.getValues =  function() {
    var val = $(".multi").map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    return val;
}
```

[**fiddle get values on click**](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/d0Laxh6j/9/)

Answer (score 0):

there is some issue on the dhtml part, You may need to change your html part as like below

jsfiddle  link

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/d0Laxh6j/6/`

<input type="button" value="Check Selections" onclick="alert($('[name=offset]').val());">
```